# Как можно модифицировать код (Пайтон)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучала Пайтон (я новичок, буквально неделю назад начала изучение) и наткнулась на такую интересную задачку:
У нас есть торговый автомат с фруктами, у каждого фрукта свой номер начиная с 0.
Нужно написать программу, которая возьмет число n в качестве ввода от покупателя и выдаст фрукт, который соответствует данному числу
Вот список : `fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]`

Написала я в общем такой код:

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]
num = str((input)("ВВедите номер продукта: "))
if int(num) > 7 and int(num) < 20:
    a = int(num) % 10
    print(fruits[1])
    print(fruits[a])
elif len((num)) > 1 and int(num) < 10:
    a = int(num)
    print(fruits[0])
    print(fruits[a])
else:
    print(fruits[int(num)])
```

Итог: Код работает исправно, на пример если я впишу "02", то он мне выдаст apple и banana, как и должно быть. И так двухзначные цифры работаю вплоть до того момента, пока они не станут больше 20

Вопрос: Можно ли как-то модифицировать данный код? Просто по моему, он получился больно длинным, да мне и самой интересно послушать мнение сенпаев)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fruits = ["apple", "cherry", "banana", "kiwi", "lemon", "pear", "peach", "avocado"]

for i in input('Enter code:'):
    try:
        print(fruits[int(i)])
    except:
        print('Wrong code!!!')
```

В переменной i в цикле будет по одной букве из пользовательского ввода.

В блоке try питон пытается преобразовать букву к целому числу и выдать фрукт по номеру.

Если выпадает исключение - выполняется блок except

Comment: а если фруктов больше 10? :)

Comment: фигасе, это как так-то? Может объяснишь? Просто я еще не дошла до момента с циклом for

Comment: @PocketDream edited.